# Apply style using javascript to last element(class:column) in div having class:container

Tags: javascript

I've the following code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="four column">some text</div>
 <div class="eight column">some text</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="six column">some text</div>
 <div class="six column">some text</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="twelve column">some text</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to add style to last div (class:'column') in each div having class 'container'
I've to do it using javascript. No jquery. So, that the code becomes:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="four column">some text</div>
 <div class="eight column" style='margin-right:0px;'>some text</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="six column">some text</div>
 <div class="six column" style='margin-right:0px;>some text</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="twelve column" style='margin-right:0px;>some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your javascript code? Also, you can do it purely in css. No need of javascript at all

Answer (score 1):

You can try somethig like:

```
var containerDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

for (var i=0, iLen=containerDivs.length; i<iLen; i++) {

  var columnElements = containerDivs[i].querySelectorAll('.column');
  var last = columnElements[columnElements.length - 1];
}
```

The query selector API isn't supported by IE 7 and lower.

If IE 8 was a bit more sophisticated inside the for loop you might be able to use:

```
var last = containerDivs[i].querySelector('.column:last-of-type');
```

or even remove the loop altogether with:

```
var lastColumns = document.querySelectorAll('.container > .column:last-of-type');
```

And you can use pure CSS:

```
.container > .column:last-of-type {
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

but IE 8 doesn't support that either. You can do it with loops and a function to do the work of *getElementsByClassName* in browsers where it's lacking.

Comment: but I want it to be supported in all browsers. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container").lastElementChild.style.marginRight = "0px";
```

Comment: *lastElementChild* is [not supported in IE 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html) and [*getElementsByClassName*](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) (which IE 8 doesn't support either) returns a collection.